# In MVC is there any Mandatory for Declaring View Name and Action Method are Same?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have one View With Name Test in Home Folder and I have a HomeController and i Declare one Action Method Name Test1.When i run the App it gets an Error..

```
public ActionResult Test1()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

when changed Method Name Test1() to Test() it successed

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

....so.it is Mandatory to Declare View name and Action Method names same or Not

Comment: What error. And you can have different names, but you then need to specify the view name in `return View("yourViewName");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to have the same `.cshtml` filename as the action in the view. For example, you could have:

```
/views/home/Test.cshtml
```

Then in the `home` controller say:

```
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    return View();
}
```

or, you could say:

```
/views/home/my-view.cshtml
```

then in the `home` controller:

```
[ActionName("my-view")]
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes...but you could put your view in the `/views/shared` folder as MVC will look there if it doesn't find the view in the controllers corresponding view folder

Comment: No problem. please mark up the answer if it helped :-)

Comment: When i Press UpMark it Shows Some Error